# Register to unity or added as reference

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism, composition, prism-4

I have 3 module in my application. And 1 ServiceLibrary.

```
Module1
Module2
Module3

ServiceLibrary
```

ServiceLibrary will be registered to Unity when Bootstrapper added modules so ServiceLibrary registered to Unity in Module1. Like:

```
_container.RegisterType<ISystemService>,ServiceLibrary>();
```

And that service can called by all other Modules too. So when its called for example Module2 it will just resolve and use it in Module2 like:

```
ISytemService myserv=_container.Resolve<ISystemService>("ServiceLibrary");
```

So which approach is good for performance?

Adding that ServiceLibrary as referencte to Modules or Using as above as resolving it from Unity when it needed to use. In project there is more than 100 service library like that.

Answer (score 0):

Module1, Module2, Module3 & ServiceLibrary should reference a separate assembly that contains `IServiceLibrary` and a list of WellKnownService names, and concrete instances should be obtained using Unity:

```
ISytemService myserv=_container.Resolve<ISystemService>(WellKnownNames.ServiceLibrary);
```

Adding references in Modules to `ServiceLibrary` removes the whole point of using an IoC container like Unity.

Comment: Adding references in Modules to ServiceLibrary removes the whole point of using an IoC container like Unity. so is that better for performance?

Comment: Without measuring it I couldn't say but I imagine any performance benefits would be tiny while the negative impact on maintainability would be huge. Every time you wanted to add a new service you'd have to recompile your app.